# Resolution filtering in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know screen resolutions can be duplicated due to different screen refresh rates. I need to filter the values so that the screen resolutions work correctly.

```
        resolutionDropdown.ClearOptions(); 

        resolutions = Screen.resolutions;//.Where(resolution => resolution.refreshRate == Screen.currentResolution.refreshRate).ToArray(); 

        
        List<string> options = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < resolutions.Length; i++) 
        {
                Debug.Log("resolutions[i].refreshRate = " + resolutions[i].refreshRateRatio);
                Debug.Log(resolutions[i].width + " " + resolutions[i].height);

                string option = resolutions[i].width + " x " + resolutions[i].height + " " + resolutions[i].refreshRateRatio; 
                options.Add(option); 

                if (resolutions[i].Equals(Screen.currentResolution)) 
                {
                    currResolutionIndex = i; 
                }
            
        }

        resolutionDropdown.AddOptions(options); 
        resolutionDropdown.value = currResolutionIndex; 
        resolutionDropdown.RefreshShownValue(); 

        if (currResolutionIndex == -1) 
                {
                    
                    Screen.SetResolution(Screen.width, Screen.height, isFullscreen);
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    Screen.SetResolution(Screen.resolutions[currResolutionIndex].width, Screen.resolutions[currResolutionIndex].height, isFullscreen);
                }
```

So I'm trying to filter the values based on the current screen refresh rate. Unfortunately, when filtering, resolutions start to work incorrectly, the game becomes blurry and black bars appear on the sides. Without filtering and choosing the same resolution (as with filtering) with the same screen refresh rate, it works fine. In the code filtering is commented out.

Comment: the proportions are often the crutial issue, plus blurry? well it can look blurry because its pixelated and your monitor is estimating having a lower resolution.. this is all normal..

Comment: the problem is that if I don't use filtering, for example, when selecting 1920x1080 75hz, then everything works fine, and when filtering and selecting the same value, the picture changes, it gets worse.

Comment: This is the perfect example of why games ask to confirm a resolution change with a countdown timer, which if due, game reverts to the previous resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I just assigned a value for the screen resolution through Screen.resolutions instead of resolutions

```
public void ChangeResolution(int index) 
{
    currResolutionIndex = index;
    Screen.SetResolution(resolutions[currResolutionIndex].width, resolutions[currResolutionIndex].height, isFullscreen);
}
```